# Picasso Library detects if the image updated in the server

Tags: android, image, url, server, picasso

I've been searching around trying to find a solution for my question but I didn't find any helpful answers . I'm still new to android development.

I want to know Is there any way to let picasso  detect if the image update in the same link so if it is update it load it to my app , but if it is still the same one (I mean it is not update it) get it from cache. This is my code:

```
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).
into(imageView, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
       @Override

       public void onSuccess() {

           progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such way to detect any change of image file content in picasso or to my best knowledge any asynchronous image loading library